# cannot use pcl after reinstalling it

Tags: ubuntu, printer-control-language

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed pcl-1.8 at first. Since I want to use pcl-1.7, I simply deleted the pcl-related files in
 `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/share`. Then I run `sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev` and the new pcl-1.7 headfiles are installed in `/usr/include`. However, when I try to run pcl_viewer, the system still tries to find the `libpcl_visualization.so.1.8` in the local path.

Does anyone has an idea of this?